# make Intellij to use a line break after annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying **IntelliJ** to see how it compares with **Eclipse** in Java development. I have imported the Eclipse code format. 
But the Intellij still gives me this format: `@Override public void run()`. What I want is this:

```
@Override 
public void run()
```

Searched online and tried a few settings, no one works to me.

Anybody can help me with this?

BTW, I cannot understand why IntelliJ needs a plugin to have the "Save Action". By looking at the download count for that plugin, it is very clear that the "Save Action" is one of the most wanted functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA default code style always wraps the annotations. You can control it here:

[image: wrap always]

You can also use [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) plug-in instead to get the same formatting as in Eclipse.